# Creating a rss feed and having some trouble with Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I can't seem to be able to get any images or titles from the mysql database even though I am connected, to the actual rss feed, and i am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php
define ("DB_HOST", "xxx"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "xxx"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS","fgbsh"); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","adfgadg"); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

$query = "SELECT story, description, pic, url FROM ".posts." WHERE status=1 ORDER BY   time_added desc";
$getBlogDisplay = mysql_query($query);

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
<title></title>
<link></link>
<description></description>
<language>en-us</language>"; 


while($dataBlogDisplay = mysql_fetch_array($getBlogDisplay)){

 $title         = $dataBlogDisplay['story']; 
 $link          = $dataBlogDisplay['url'];
$description    = $dataBlogDisplay['pic'];

echo "<item> 
<title>$title</title>
<link>$url</link>
<description>$description</description>
</item>"; 
} 
echo "</channel></rss>";
?>
```

and I am pretty sure my tables are named correctly too. This is the tutorial I have been using

http://www.discussdesk.com/create-rss-feed-with-php-mysql.htm

Comment: What errors are you getting? Errors help you to diagnose the problem and troubleshoot.

Comment: You're not checking the return status of your query here: `$getBlogDisplay = mysql_query($query);`. If you did you'd know that you need to fix the syntax error here:`... url FROM ".posts." WHERE st...`. (note missing `$`) Where is `$posts` defined?

Comment: BTW - the `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated and will be removed. You shouldn't use them for new code. I suggest you find a better tutorial that uses `mysqli_*()` or `PDO`.