# Adding images to rss feed by using php

Tags: php, rss

So i just finished making a rss feed for my website, the image that is suppose to be in the rss feed is not showing at all. All its showing is the title and the filename. Is there a way for me to add some extra code that grabs the image and places the image in the rss feed.

btw this part - $description    = $dataBlogDisplay['pic'];  is suppose to get the picture but all it displays is the filename.

here is my code

```
<?php
define ("DB_HOST", "xxx"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "xxx"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS","xxxx"); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","xxxx"); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

$query = "select story, url, pic from `posts` limit 20";
$getBlogDisplay = mysql_query($query);

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
<title></title>
<link></link>
<description></description>
<language>en-us</language>"; 


while($dataBlogDisplay = mysql_fetch_array($getBlogDisplay)){

 $title         = $dataBlogDisplay['story']; 
 $link          = $dataBlogDisplay['url'];
$description    = $dataBlogDisplay['pic'];


echo "<item> 
<title>$title</title>
<link><![CDATA[http://www.xxxxxx.com/post/$description]]></link>
<description>$description</description>


</item>"; 
} 
echo "</channel></rss>";
?>
```

Comment: Hello again. I see you're still asking questions about the same bad 'tutorial', yet you haven't responded to comments left on your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322219/creating-a-rss-feed-and-having-some-trouble-with-mysql) on this very topic.

Comment: thats because I figured out how to lose the issue on the last on.

Answer (score -1):

image should be place in this

```
 <image>
  <url>http://www.w3schools.com/images/logo.gif</url>
  <title>W3Schools.com</title>
  <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
 </image>
```

Take a look at this. http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_image.asp

Comment: Two reasons for downvoting this. Firstly, you haven't indicated how this relates to the OPs code, and secondly, W3Schools is know for it's poorly presented and often inaccurate information.

Comment: @MikeW Im sorry. Every time i used w3s information it was correct, Maybe your right and sometime there is some mistake on there, il consider it before next Answer on a question.   also sorry for my ignorance but what is "OPs code" ?